# google Apps script using mailApp to send htmlbody (content being modified)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was trying to send an approval letter with google apps script (mailApp).
And hide some data in the hidden input.
However, the id of the input was changed by google.

The script in google apps script:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: email,
    subject: "Classroom register Approval",
    body: "",
    htmlBody: 
      "<form action = 'google apps script website' method = 'POST'>" +
      "<input id='approverow' type='hidden' value="+ e.range.getRowIndex() +">" +
      "<button type = \"submit\">Approve</button>"
  })
```

real HTML in email

```
<form action="google apps script website" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input id="m_8985313804230818410approverow" type="hidden" value="22">
<button type="submit">Approve</button></form>
```

Why Google change the element id and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

I think the `id` is only getting modified when being displayed in the corresponding `INBOX`, but it's not modified in the message itself.

#### Explanation:

As you probably know, the `id` of an element must be unique in the whole document. So I think this is a way to ensure that the `id` is unique in the page in which it is being displayed (e.g. `INBOX`). Think, for example, what would happen if the `id` you specified matched the one in Gmail sidebar?

More importantly, you can notice that if you retrieve the message body once it has been sent (via `GmailApp.search`, or what have you) **the `id` of the message is the one you specified, no modification**.

Also, this is not particular to Google: you can check that the `id` gets modified in different ways depending on where the email is being displayed. While messages displayed in Gmail `INBOX` get appended something like `m{many numbers}`, messages displayed in Outlook get appended `x_`. And a similar behaviour seems to occur for the `class` attribute: in Outlook, `class` attributes from the email body also get `x_` appended, while in Gmail, `class` is not even present.